# Doxygen: EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS excludes primary template and specializations all at once

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen, template-specialization

Consider the following snippet:

```
template<typename>
struct F;

/**
 * documentation
 */
template<typename R, typename... A>
struct F<R(A...)> {
    // ...
};
```

I'd like to generate documentation for the template specialization. On the other side, I want to exclude the primary template because it's not defined and it doesn't make much sense to document it.

I tried using `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` for it looks the most promising candidate.
Anyway, the following suppresses the generation for both the primary template and its specializations:

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = F
```

I've experimented for a while with other alternatives but none of them worked.
Is there any way to get it with `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS`? Otherwise, there exists  any other method to do that?

Comment: Doxygen [claims](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) it’s “the de facto standard tool for generating documentation from annotated C++ sources, but it also supports other popular programming languages such as C, Objective-C, C#, PHP, Java, Python, IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors), Fortran, VHDL, Tcl, and to some extent D”, but I’ve always found its support for more complex features felt like an afterthought.